# How do I change the internal log priority in oat++ to PRIORITY_V?

Tags: oat++

How do I change the internal log priority in oat++ to PRIORITY_V?

```
std::shared_ptr<oatpp::base::Logger> logger = oatpp::base::Environment::getLogger();
```

I could not find a fucntion to change the priority.

Comment: Hello @Molitoris, if you want to make oatpp itself to output more logs, then you can't do it. Oat++ does not log much in it's own code.
If you want to filter Logger output - then implement your own Logger or add corresponding compiler flags to silence log channels.

Answer (score 0):

As [@lganzzzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5664910/lganzzzo) comments, Oat++ does not write many logs itself, but you can control your own logs. Also, these are independent channels: you can enable verbose, and disable debug and information, for example. As far as I see in the code of the DefaultLogger, all logs are enabled by default (including Verbose).

There is an example on how to configure the logs: https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp/blob/master/test/oatpp/core/base/LoggerTest.cpp. In the following excerpt of that example, it takes the default logger and disables the Debug priority, while other priorities (including Verbose) stay enabled):

```
  auto logger = std::static_pointer_cast<oatpp::base::DefaultLogger>(oatpp::base::Environment::getLogger());

  OATPP_LOGV("LoggerTest", "Verbose Log")
  OATPP_LOGD("LoggerTest", "Debug Log")
  OATPP_LOGI("LoggerTest", "Info Log")
  OATPP_LOGW("LoggerTest", "Warning Log")
  OATPP_LOGE("LoggerTest", "Error Log")

  OATPP_LOGI("LoggerTest", " --- Disabling Debug Log")
  logger->disablePriority(oatpp::base::DefaultLogger::PRIORITY_D);
  OATPP_ASSERT(!logger->isLogPriorityEnabled(oatpp::base::DefaultLogger::PRIORITY_D))

  OATPP_LOGV("LoggerTest", "Verbose Log")
  OATPP_LOGD("LoggerTest", "Debug Log")     //this won't be written
  OATPP_LOGI("LoggerTest", "Info Log")
  OATPP_LOGW("LoggerTest", "Warning Log")
  OATPP_LOGE("LoggerTest", "Error Log")
```